# How to filter data of type specified in array in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i try to filter my mongo database to get data that types included in array, adn filter certain type further. my filter is like this

```
db.event.find({
  $or: [{ date: { $lte: new Date().toISOString() } }, { status: 'DONE' }],
  type: { $in: ['PUBLIC', 'TEAM', 'PRIVATE'] },
  team: ObjectId("512e28984815cbfcb21646a7")
})
```

with those filter i aimed to get event that was ended, which type is all mentioned in array, and for `TEAM` type, it will search only event that has team id specified. But using that filter i get nothing, anyone know how to achieve my intention?

Comment: please share your sample collection data to perform such cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the expressions in [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) operator like in the [eg](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#and-queries-with-multiple-expressions-specifying-the-same-operator)

Comment: thanks, i modified it a bit based on your suggestion and now it works!